# get event on scrollstart and scrollend - iscroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, iscroll

I am using iScroll v5.1.1, and I want event when user started and ended scrolling activity on the page.

Here is my javascript,

```
myScroll = new IScroll('#scrollinginside', {
    scrollbars: true,
    mouseWheel: true,
    interactiveScrollbars: true,
    shrinkScrollbars: 'scale',
    fadeScrollbars: false,
    checkDOMChanges: true,
    onScrollStart: function () {
        console.log('scrolling is started');
    },
    onScrollEnd: function () {
        console.log('scrolling stopped');
    }
});
```

But when I tried to scroll across the page no event is registred. Whats wrong with my javascript ? Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved this problem by using ,

```
myScroll = new IScroll('#scrollinginside', {
    scrollbars: true,
    mouseWheel: true,
    interactiveScrollbars: true,
    shrinkScrollbars: 'scale',
    fadeScrollbars: false,
    checkDOMChanges: true
});


myScroll.on ('scrollStart', function () {
console.log('Started');
});
myScroll.on ('scrollEnd', function () {
console.log('Ended');
});
```